# Resetting a vuex module's state to some initialState value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm attempting to come up with a method which can reset a modules state back to some initial value, and so far I am coming up o a few conceptual issues.

My base store is the following:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    moduleA: moduleA,
  },
  actions: {
    resetAllState: ({ dispatch }) => {"moduleA");
    },
    resetModuleState: (currentModule) => {
      // Perform the reset here...somehow?
    }
  }
});
```

The `moduleA.js` store is created as follows with an `intialState`:

```
const initialState = () => ({
   helloWorld: {}  
});

const moduleA = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    initialState: initialState(),
    ...initialState(),
  }
};

export default moduleA;
```

So I utilise a spread operator to create the following:

```
const moduleA = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    initialState: initialState(),
    helloWord: {}
  }
};
```

I can then mutate `state.helloWorld` whilst keeping a copy of the `state.initialState`...

So, my question now is, within the following global store

```
    resetModuleState: (currentModule) => {
      // Perform the reset here...somehow?
    }
```

action, how do I actually perform the reset?

I have treid this as a global way of resetting state:

```
resetAllState: function() {
      let defaultState = {};
      Object.keys(store.state).forEach((key) => {
        defaultState = {
          ...defaultState,
          [key]: store.state[key].initialState ? store.state[key].initialState : store.state[key],
        };
      });
      store.replaceState(Object.assign({}, defaultState));
    },
```

But to no luck...?

Comment: this issue also resolved based on the previous question you asked

Comment: @chans I would say this question is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is having issue, the actions can have only access to

```
{ commit, dispatch, getters } as params
```

In above code "resetModuleState" takes modueleName in the first parameter, but it will have an object, so directly access the module object by below approach and reset the stathe by just calling initialState() function from each module you have

> use this code inside the action "resetAllState"

```
resetAllState: function({ dispatch }) {
    this._modules.root.forEachChild((childModule) => {
      childModule.state.initialState();
    });
},
```

Comment: Hi chans - I believe this answer to be slightly different...I'd like to reset the state from the global `resetModuleState` action targeting the module...

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos, I've updated the answer, try this approach, you issue will be resolved

Comment: Hmmmm, `'currentModule' is assigned a value but never used (no-unused-vars)` and `'modules' is not defined`

Comment: Updated the above answer, now you can check, thanks for the call out

Comment: `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: childModule.state.initialState is not a function"` and you don't need to pass in `dispatch`, unless you use it.

Comment: put console log for childModule, and see what you can access

Comment: I don't have you codebase setup, I'm just giving a solution or a fix, you just debug and do some addons to reset all modules state